# Android Mapsforge out of memory when starting 2 or more activities with map

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks, maps

I created app with mapsforge library. 
I have 3 activities with MapView on each activity. When I start two or more activities the app crashes with out of memory:

```
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at org.mapsforge.android.maps.FrameBuffer.onSizeChanged(FrameBuffer.java:179)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at org.mapsforge.android.maps.MapView.onSizeChanged(MapView.java:574)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:14141)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14053)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14055)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4604)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1992)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1813)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-09 10:42:59.005: E/AndroidRuntime(23825):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it possible to release and restore MapView in activity lifecycle to avoid this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the better way to avoid out of memory exception is to remove map view from activity when it is not visible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?